# $test$plusargs unexpectedly matches a substring

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

We usually write testcases with VCS plusargs as follows

```
if($test$plusargs("Hello"))
    do_hello_stimulus();
else if($test$plusargs("Hello1"))
    do_hello1_stimulus();
```

But, I found out `$test$plusargs` matches even a substring. Even if we pass `Hello1`, it will call `do_hello_stimulus()`. How I should match an exact string?

Answer (score 3):

this is exactly the behavior defined in the standard. The $test$plusargs matches the prefix of an arg.

You can use the $value$plusargs instead to check the remainder of the string. Something like this:

```
if ($value$plusargs("hello%s", rest)) begin
    if (rest == "")
        $display("hello");
    else 
        $display("hello: %s", rest);
end
else
    $display("error");
```